# Calculating simple effect without an interaction!? - arguments needed

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures, interaction

As far as I can tell this question has never been asked before. There are several questions that touch on related issues, but none of them have provided a definitive answer to this question.

I have a two-way design (group and time) with repeated measures (baseline + 2 x Post intervention); thus 2 x groups and 3 time points.

In one of my statistical tests I get a significant main time effect and no interaction (time*group) with a mixed model. Normally I would interpret this, as both groups carrying the same effect over time. However, my data indicated a larger effect at the earlier time point in one of my groups (resulting in a interaction P value of 0.11), while the other showed a more modest change.

Furthermore the overall main time effect do not take into account any potential temporal changes in these parameters, but only the overall time effect. Thus, as the interaction normally holds relative low power; I consider to calculate the simple time effects within each group - i.e. to get a feeling about the change with time within the separate groups. This is also based on the behaviour of related analyses indicating that a negative response could be expected in the group going down and up again.

That said - I am aware of most sources advice not to or state that is it not neccessary to make simple effect analysis, when no significant interactions are present. However, I have not been able to locate a strict argument why it is advisable to absolutely refrain from calculating simple effect without a significant interaction.

Hope someone will take the time to explain this or provide me with a link explaining this.

[image: Data depiction]